# Issue reading an cvs file in the server

Tags: c#, file-upload, server

I am having issues reading a cvs file that is in the server. I know for sure that is not a folder permission issue because I am able to upload and delete the file in the server.

the problem is here:   using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"FullDomain/MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.cvs"))

This code works in local if I change the file location for a local path @"c:etc"
I will really appreaciate any help!

code:

```
 protected void btnPreviewFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string line = null;
        int i = 0;

   try{

       using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"fullDomain/MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.cvs"))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] data = line.Split(',');
                if (data.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in data)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = data;
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);

                    LabelAlert.Text = "Preview good";

                    //Display data in a GridView control 
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }

   }catch(Exception ex){

    LabelAlert.Text = ex.ToString();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Use Server.MapPath("MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.csv"); you need to specify the full path to your folder.

Comment: Hi Mihai, thank you for you answer, could you please tell exactly where to use your solution within my code? because this is giving me an error:  using (StreamReader sr = Server.MapPath("MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.csv"))

Comment: Pass the path to File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.csv"))

Comment: ok let me test it thank you!

Comment: It's typically called a CSV file, by the way: Comma Separated Values.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I missed that :)

Comment: Mihai, i am getting this error:  System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported. at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) ... any ideas?

Comment: How did you modified the code? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that Mihai gave me.

I replace this line

```
    `using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"fullDomain/MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.cvs"))`
```

with

```
   `using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("/MyCVSFolder/Promocodes.cvs")))`
```